# How do I change a text_field in Rails into radio buttons with Bootstrap?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

I'm using Bootstrap to create a form and I have two text fields where you can enter either 'yes' or 'no'.
Instead of entering text, would it be possible to create two radio buttons instead called 'yes' or 'no'?

```
<%= form_with(model: evaluation) do |form| %>
  <% if evaluation.errors.any? %>
    <div style="color: red">
      <h2><%= pluralize(evaluation.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this evaluation from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% evaluation.errors.each do |error| %>
          <li><%= error.full_message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :name, style: "display: block" %>
    <%= form.text_field :name, class:"form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :be_humbly_confident, style: "display: block" %>
    <%= form.text_field :be_humbly_confident, class:"form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :grow_or_die, style: "display: block" %>
    <%= form.text_field :grow_or_die, class:"form-control" %>
  </div>
```

This is what I want to create, but don't know how to amend it that it works with my form and updates the index page.

```
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="flexRadioDefault1">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1">
    Default radio
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="flexRadioDefault2" checked>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault2">
    Default checked radio
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Would form.select satisfy your needs? https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#select-boxes-and-model-objects

Answer (score 0):

RoR has built in helpers for creating such items in forms. See [form.select](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#select-boxes-and-model-objects)